# How to fix karaf dependency error for com.google.common.base

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf

I try to deploy a .kar file into karaf that has some dependencies. I get this error:

```
2017-02-07 17:23:17,501 | ERROR | nsole user karaf | ShellUtil         | 74 - org.apache.karaf.shell.core - 4.0.5 | Exception caught while executing command org.apache.karaf.shell.support.MultiException: Error executing command on bundles:
                Error starting bundle 161: Unable to resolve de.dentrassi.camel.milo.camel-milo [161](R 161.0): missing requirement [de.dentrassi.camel.milo.camel-milo [161](R 161.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=19.0.0)(!(version>=20.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[de.dentrassi.camel.milo.camel-milo [161](R
161.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=19.0.0)(!(version>=20.0.0)))]
                at org.apache.karaf.shell.support.MultiException.throwIf(MultiException.java:61)
                at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:69)[52:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.5]
                at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.execute(BundlesCommand.java:54)[52:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.5]
                at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.action.command.ActionCommand.execute(ActionCommand.java:83)[74:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.5]
                at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:67)[74:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.5]
                at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:87)[74:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.5]
                at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:480)[74:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.5]
                at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:406)[74:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.5]
                at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[74:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.5]
                at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:182)[74:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.5]
                at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:119)[74:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.5]
                at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:94)[74:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.5]
                at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.ConsoleSessionImpl.run(ConsoleSessionImpl.java:270)[74:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.5]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_121] Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error starting bundle 161: Unable to resolve de.dentrassi.camel.milo.camel-milo [161](R 161.0): missing requirement [de.dentrassi.camel.milo.camel-milo [161](R 161.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=19.0.0)(!(version>=20.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[de.dentrassi.camel.milo.camel-milo [161](R
161.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=19.0.0)(!(version>=20.0.0)))]
                at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:66)[52:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.5]
                ... 12 more
```

This would be fine, but this package is part of guava, which is part of my deployment. When i check the installed bundles, i see

> 1 | Active    |  50 | 19.0.0                             | Guava:
>   Google Core Libraries for Java

And only this related to guava. So there should not be a conflicting dependency. 
I checked the export of the guava bundle with

> bundle:headers 1

and got

```
Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java (1)
-----------------------------------------
Bnd-LastModified = 1449694703480
Build-Jdk = 1.7.0-google-v5
Built-By = cgdecker
Created-By = Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Manifest-Version = 1.0
Tool = Bnd-1.50.0

Bundle-Description = Guava is a suite of core and expanded libraries that include    utility classes, google's collections, io classes, and much    much more.    Guava has only one code dependency - javax.annotation,    per the JSR-305 spec.
Bundle-DocURL = https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/
Bundle-License = http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
Bundle-ManifestVersion = 2
Bundle-Name = Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java
Bundle-SymbolicName = com.google.guava
Bundle-Version = 19.0.0

Export-Package = 
    com.google.common.net;
        uses:="javax.annotation,
            com.google.common.base,
            com.google.common.hash,
            com.google.common.io,
            com.google.common.primitives,
            com.google.common.collect,
            com.google.common.escape";
        version=19.0.0,
```

I looked for duplicate exports with

> package:exports -d

But only some unrelated were duplicates:

```
Package Name                                 | Version | Exporting bundles (ID)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.component.event             | 2.18.0  | 195 194
org.apache.camel.language.spel               | 2.18.0  | 195 194
org.apache.camel.spring.converter            | 2.18.0  | 195 194
org.apache.camel.spring.handler              | 2.18.0  | 195 194
org.apache.camel.spring.pollingconsumer      | 2.18.0  | 195 194
org.apache.camel.spring.processor.idempotent | 2.18.0  | 195 194
org.apache.camel.spring.remoting             | 2.18.0  | 195 194
org.apache.camel.spring.spi                  | 2.18.0  | 195 194
org.apache.camel.spring.util                 | 2.18.0  | 195 194
org.apache.camel.spring                      | 2.18.0  | 195 194
org.apache.camel.util.spring                 | 2.18.0  | 195 194
```

I am stuck here. Could you give me a hand how to debug this?

EDIT: I made the mistake looking for guava with bundle:list. This omits all bundles with runlevel < 50. I used la instead and discovered two bundles:
Guava 18.0.0 and Guava 19.0.0. Is there a way to have both versions installed at the same time?

Comment: Note: post stack traces as code (indent by 4), rather than as blockquotes (line starts with `>`). They are basically unreadable unless printed in monospace font.

Comment: Sorry, should have known. Fixed that.